# Css global counters

Tags: html, css

According to css spec (http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/generate.html#scope), resetting a counter  automatically creates a new instance of the counter.

I am trying to workaround this behavior in order to handle global counters which would not take the div tree structure into account when being reset.

See below example

css

```css
body {
    counter-reset: counter1 0 counter2 0;
}

.counter1 {
    counter-increment: counter1;
    counter-reset: counter2 0;
}

    .counter1:before {
        content: counter(counter1);
    }

.counter2 {
    counter-increment: counter2;
}

    .counter2:before {
        content: counter(counter1) ". " counter(counter2);
    }
```

```html
<body>
    <div>
        <div class="counter1">Section 1</div>
        <div class="counter2">SubItem 1.1</div>
    </div>
    <div>
        <div class="counter2">SubItem 1.2</div>
    </div>
    <div>
        <div class="counter2">SubItem 1.3</div>
    </div>
    <div>
        <div class="counter1">Section 2</div>
        <div class="counter2">SubItem 2.1</div>
    </div>
    <div>
        <div class="counter2">SubItem 2.2</div>
    </div>
</body>
```

Any ideas ?

Comment: Does each subitem always appear in its own outer div, optionally with a section header? In other words, will each outer div only ever contain either 1) a header followed by a subitem or 2) a single subitem?

Comment: No. I can have 2 subitems in the same div.
Actually I really would like to have the counters independent from the dom nesting structure (except of course for the order of appearance in the tree)

Comment: I don't think there is a CSS-based workaround for this behavior. There does not seem to be any way to change it.

Comment: Thanks. I guess I have to handle it on the server side or with javascript.

Answer (score 0):

Do you need something like this http://jsfiddle.net/9x492j2m/

You can have your elements in ul list

```
<ul class="counter1">
    <li>Section 1
        <ul class="counter2">
            <li>SubItem 1.1</li>
            <li>SubItem 1.2</li>
            <li>SubItem 1.3</li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li>Section 2
        <ul class="counter2">
            <li>SubItem 2.1</li>
            <li>SubItem 2.2</li>
            <li>SubItem 2.3</li>
            <li>Subitem 2.4</li>
        </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
```

And then the CSS

```
.counter1 {
    counter-reset: counter1;   
    list-style: none;
}
.counter1 li:before {
    content: counter(counter1);
    counter-increment:counter1;
    color: #fff;
    background: red;    
}
.counter2 {
    counter-reset: counter2;    
}
.counter2 li:before {
    content: counter(counter1)". " counter(counter2);
    counter-increment:counter2;
}
```

Comment: I do not think it works for me.
In my use case, html elements indentation does not correspond to the expected numbering structure. Sub items for instance may appear  in a node which is neither a child or even a sibling of the main parent item.